# overlaying an iframe over another iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Im trying to overlay an iframe, over another iframe via javascript.

I want to keep the background iframe to be 100% width and height, but the second iframe i want it to appear slightly smaller and in the center of the first iframe.

Currently im trying to set the two iframes as below, but that does not seem to work..

```
<div id="iframe1" style="width=80%; height=50%;">
    <iframe id="gameIFrame" style="width=80%; height=50%;position:absolute;  z-index:1000;" seamless="seamless" src="http://www.guguncube.com" />
</div>

<div id="iframe2" style="width=30%; height=30%;" >
    <iframe id="gameIFrame2" style="width=30%; height=30%; position:absolute; " seamless="seamless" src="http://www.guguncube.com"/>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your styles use "=" insead of ":"

Comment: I believe you'll have difficulty using percentages for your dimensions. You need to know the height of your <divs> so that you can figure out how to center #iframe2 vertically with margin-top (the calculation being 1/2 the height of #iframe1 minus 1/2 the height of #iframe2) You can give it a whirl with relative units, but I've always found it more reliable to use absolute units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , it can be done, not a problem. The problem that you have here is that, while you are loading frame2 in frame1 , then you need to center it using `top and left` attributes.

Again, the usage of attrs namely: `seamless and zindex` are not required.

This is the full code :

```
<iframe id="gameIFrame1" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;   display: block; position: absolute;" src="http://www.guguncube.com">
</iframe>

<iframe id="gameIFrame2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 50px;    left: 50px;    display: block;    position: absolute;" src="http://www.guguncube.com">
</iframe>
```

Find the fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/cxbmu/1/ , where you obviously can see the screen shot of what you are expecting it to be .

Comment: Okay that worked, thanks for that. Does anyone know how to disable the clicks in an iframe? So my underlying iframe is still clickable.. i dont want that to be possible when another iframe is over the top.

Comment: What you are asking about disabling click events in the inner iframe is not possible, as that is hosted in another domain. That's what `Same Origin Policy` is all about . See this : Same Origin Policy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFNUa/

You may want to specify: `display:block;` on your iframes. Also, specify top/left positions carefully when doing a `position:absolute;`

A word of caution though: It may not be a good idea to overlap iframes. iframes are meant to be islands within a window, overlapping kills usability.